# GNI public coin interactive proof: why randomize y?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, graph-isomorphism, interactive-proof-systems

I've read [this](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Ezacharyf/courses/complexity_2019/notes/complexity-w19-lec12.pdf) scribe that provides a public coin interactive proof for graph non-isomorphism.

In the proof, the verifier samples both a pairwise-independent hash function **and a target $y$**. Then it continues to show bounds for the probability that there's a pre-image of $y$ w.r.t. the hash function that's also inside a given subdomain $S$.

In all calculations carried out in page 5 (lemma 3), I couldn't find a single instance that used the fact that $y$ is random. It seems as if randomizing the hash function is enough.

This is also the case for any other source I found that shows a specific public-coin interactive proof for GNI.

Why do we need to randomize $y$?

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your question to make it self-contained by providing relevant background and defining the notation.  Also it would help to identify which part of that 7-page document you are referring to (e.g., Section number, page number, which lemma/theorem/proof).  Also it might helpful to provide a proper reference in addition to the link (e.g., title of the document, author, class, semester), so we can find the document in the future if the link stops working.

Comment: Of course, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree.  I believe you are correct.  As far as I can see, $y$ does not need to be random.